# iTunes Connect App Name vs. Bundle Display name in info.plist

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm wondering is there a difference between iTunes Connect App Name that you enter vs. the Bundle Display name in info.plist?

I saw some posts that mention you can easily change your app name displayed under your icon on the iphone by just changing info.plist.  How does that work without changing the iTunes Connect App Name to match?  For example, could I type in "Facebook" into my info.plist for an update while my iTunes Connect App Name says "MyMadeUpAppName?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The name in iTunes Connect will appear in the App Store; the Info.plist display name will appear on the home screen.

Comment: as an example, is there anything that stops me from naming my app "Facebook" then?  the reason i'm asking is because i made a mistake in my upload which invalidated the name I was using.  so, if possible, i was thinking to use "MyMadeUpAppName.com" as "App Name" in itunes connect and still retain "MyMadeUpAppName" on the iphone.

Comment: Yes, it's quite common not have exactly the same name in the App Store as on the home screen, also because the name on the home screen cannot exceed a certain number of characters. Twitterrific, for example, is called "Twitterrific for Twitter" in the App Store, but only appears as "Twitterrific" on the home screen.

Comment: Do apple reject App , if there is mismatch from the name on ITunes Connect with Info.plist ?

Answer (score 2):

Info.plist.

```
- You Set the bundle identifier to YourAppName.
- The Identifier should not contain spaces or funny characters - alphanumeric and dashes are allowed.
- If you want your app to be named something different on the actual device than its name in Xcode, change the "Bundle display name" as well.
- Set the bundle version number.
- Be sure the icon file is set.
```

iTunes

> Once you are logged in to your developer account, you can "Manage Your Applications", then "
>   Add New Application". which will show on your itunes store. **You can change your app name for your itunes store any time**

Comment: you can change any time for your app store :)

Comment: But can those people who have previously downloaded it receive an automatically update without their care? Or do they have to download/update it again?

Answer (score 1):

If you change the Bundle Display Name, you should also change your iTunes Connect App Store.

I have had a rejection referencing the following: 
2.3 Performance: Accurate Meta Data (Performance - 2.3.8)

Quote from Apple: "We noticed that the app name to be displayed on the App Store and the app name displayed on the device do not sufficiently match, which makes it difficult for users to find the app they just downloaded."

A helpful hint from Apple: "It is important NOT to change your Bundle Identifier, which is used to uniquely identify your app in the App Store. Changing the Bundle Identifier will prevent users from upgrading and will effectively introduce a new app rather than an update."

Answer (score 0):

It's been years since this is posted. But hope someone will find this useful.

Yes, you can change your Bundle identifier easily by editing your plist.

[image]

And you can change your iTunes App Store name by editing the Name under iTunes > Your App > App Store Tab > App Information

Bundle Display Name and iTunes app name should not be identical, but of course it should be somewhat similar to each other. So that the user knows it's the same app which is there in the App Store. I got my previous version approved with names in below format.

Display name : MyAppName

App Store Name : MyAppName - Country Name

For more details refer 3.4 in [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/2016-06-13/)