# How to rename an already for sale App on the App Store only, not in xcode

Tags: ios

I have found many sources that say that the App store App name can be modified only when you submit a new binary.

I have not been able to find the way to do that in the current iTunes Connect environment.  Does anyone know if this is still possible?

I have a new version with binary uploaded and a 'Submit for Review' button available and nowhere on any tab or link can I find a way to change the App Name.

I do NOT want to change the name that appears under the icon on the users iPhone!

If this is not possible any more, how do I rename an already for sale App Store App from say 'MapMinder' to 'MapMinder Map Organizer' (it is not relevant why I would want to do that!)?

If I first remove 'MapMinder' for sale status, do I not lose the ability to use MapMinder in another name?

**Edit: Well, sometimes I can't see the forest for the trees Thanks all!**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well it's definitely possible according to the [iTunes Connect Developer Guide - Replacing Your App with a New Version](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ReplacingYourAppWithANewVersion.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH14-SW1).

1. Log into iTunes connect
2. Select My Apps module
3. Select the App update to change
4. Finally the textfield to change the name as it appears in the store should be located under the screen shots and above the description field.

[image]

I hope this helps.

Comment: Wow, how did I and another person here miss that :), Thanks.

Comment: Your welcome - It's easy to overlook as there is soooo much going on with the page!

Comment: You may need to cancel any 'pending releases' before doing this.  This means you will need to have the app reviewed by App Store staff again, however.

Answer (score 2):

With next update in [iTunes Connect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com) you can change the name. That is the name used by App Store.

Bundle Name or Bundle Display Name reflect what your app is called on user's device (see https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1892/_index.html for funky details)

Also see [iTunes Connect App Name vs. Bundle Display name in info.plist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7047268/itunes-connect-app-name-vs-bundle-display-name-in-info-plist)

Comment: Sorry but I specifically asked about changing the App store name, not the name that shows on the users iPhone.  I believe all your information links are about changing what appears on the users iPhone.

Comment: See the first sentence please: "With next update in iTunes Connect you can change the name. That is the name used by App Store"

Comment: Sorry, I missed next, but I still need to know how to do it now without losing the ability to use my key application word in the next renamed app. (see question edit)

Comment: you don't need to loose anything. Once again, with next update you are going to release through iTunes Connect, you will be able to change the name of the app

Comment: Sorry Sash, I think you also had the correct answer but it took a little more banging my head against the screen for me to see the actual, clearly visible, text box :)

Comment: there is nothing stupid in asking questions;) someone will use it as a reference.

Comment: Thanks, in my defense and I am not sure there is one, it used to be harder according to my research and I was looking for an obtuse way to do it.  Glad Apple has made it easy.

Comment: Can you reuse and old name?